# Reinserting a div into a form after div has been removed from form (jQuery ui dialog)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the breakdown:

- I have a form with a large amount of form elements
- There's a jQuery div for a dialog box within the form
- The jquery dialog has dynamically generated form elements (a bunch of check boxes)

Upon submitting, my PHP processing page does not register the form elements contained in the dialog as being submitted. I've come to learn that jQuery takes the dialog division out of the position I have it located in originally (within the form), and thus it doesn't get submitted.

What I've been trying to do is clone the dialog div and place it back in the form. This isn't working, I think perhaps because cloning the div then creates two divisions with the same exact ID and this confuses things....?

Anyhow, I'm looking for any means whatsoever to be able to get the dialog's form elements submitted along with the rest of the form.

I can't believe that using a jQuery UI dialog for this purpose hasn't been done a million times--not sure what's going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting just the form elements from the dialog. You could also try appending a hidden div to the form to store the elements.

```
$('form').append($('#dialog :input').clone());
```

Comment: Jason P, I want to kiss you on the lips. Will accept your answer as soon as I'm able to.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialise both forms, and add them together before posting with jquery...

```
$('#theForm').on('submit', function(){
    var data = $('#theForm').serializeArray();
    data.push($('#theOtherForm').serializeArray());
    $.post("/theHandler/", data);
})
```